# Automating ArcGIS append Geoprocessing Tool

Tags: arcpy, append

I have about 100 feature classes inside twenty feature datasets inside a geodatabase. We have about 50 individual geodatabases. I want to load all geodatabases one by one in a one single master geodatabase. I believe anyone with experience in Python programing can help me. I don't have any coding experience.

Comment: Do you want a master table in the master gdb or just load many tables to the one master gdb?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  AS a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Questions requesting coding assistance are expected to include code.  Please **edit** the question to include your first coding attempt.

Comment: "load many gdbs" doesn't mean anything.  Geodatabases have "feature classes" (tables).  The question is *how* you want to copy all the feature classes into one geodatabase -- append identically named tables (with identical attributes), or just transfer all the uniquely named tables into new tables.

Comment: let me rephrase my question. Pardon for my poor english language . i want to automate append tool that will iterate through featuredatesets  and featureclasses inside those featuredatasets in a geodatabse and append those feature classes (Tables) Into corresponding featureclass in another gdb. both gdb have same schema .

Comment: @Vince I solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

[arcpy.da.Walk](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000023000000) was designed for this type of operation. This example assumes that all of your feature classes have unique names. If not, you will need to add logic to automatically rename duplicates.

```
import arcpy, os

inws = r"C:\temp"  # Input workspace
outws = r'C:\temp\out_data.gdb'  # Output workspace
fcs = []  # Create an empty list to store fc paths

# You can specify the type of feature classes too if you wish 
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(inws, datatype="FeatureClass")

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        fcs.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

# Loop through the fcs list and copy to a new file geodatabase
# This assumes all fc names are unique
for fc in fcs:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, os.path.join(outws, os.path.basename(fc)))
```

Comment: Thank @Aaron, I need append not copy Features. I solved it  :)